# Change table row color based on value

Tags: html, css

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
ID     |     photo      |   ident     | status
------------------------------------------------
80     |    img/photo1  |   ACH3882   |   V
81     |    img/photo2  |   SHD8837   |   V
82     |    img/photo3  |   SFF4837   |   X
83     |    img/photo4  |   DLL3266   |   V
```

Is it possible to change the rows background color, depending on the value? So if status cell value is V, make yellow, and if X make green?

This is my table, and what I have tried:

```
<table class="blueTable" border="2" style= "background-color: #f9f9f9; color: #000000; margin: 0 auto;" >
  <thead style= "background-color: #FFFFFF">
    <tr>
      <th>Photo</th>
      <th>Ident</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
     if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
          $num_rows = 0;
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $num_rows++;
                 if($row['status'] == 'V') {
                      $style = 'style="background-color:#00FF00;';
                  }
                  
                  if($row['status'] == 'X') {
                      $style = 'style="background-color:#FF00FF;';
                  }
              echo
              "<tr>
              <td>{$row['photo']}</td>
              <td>{$row['ident']}</td>
              <td>{$row['status']}</td>
              <td><a href='delete.php?id={$row['id']};'>Delete</a></td>
              </tr>";
             
          }
          /*freeresultset*/
          $result->free();
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But somehow the background color does not change. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting a question. Please edit your question to include details of what you have tried so far and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help.

Comment: Can you give us some of your code please?

Comment: @HugoAndré Sorry, forgot to paste that. Have a new look :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use your status var as a class and add the colors for the classes in css like this

```css
.color-v {
  background-color: blue;
}

.color-x {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table class="blueTable" border="2" style= "background-color: #f9f9f9; color: #000000; margin: 0 auto;" >
  <thead style= "background-color: #FFFFFF">
    <tr>
      <th>Photo</th>
      <th>Ident</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
     if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
          $num_rows = 0;
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $num_rows++;
              echo
              "<tr class='color-{$row['status']}'>
              <td>{$row['photo']}</td>
              <td>{$row['ident']}</td>
              <td>{$row['status']}</td>
              </tr>";
             
          }
          /*freeresultset*/
          $result->free();
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You are not assigning '$style' to anything but I would recommend my approach over that anyway

Comment: I just tried your code, but it does not work, none of the cells gets any color. I replaces `<tr>` with this: `"<tr class='color-{$row['status']}'>`, and added the css classes, but nothing.

Comment: If the css was set as `.color-v > td { .. }` and `.color-x > td { .. }` ... then the coloring would only apply to the td columns inside instead of the tr if that is what you meant by 'not work'.

Comment: And also check your inspector if the value gets overwritten by another selector