# Make table row background color based on value from database

Tags: php, html, css

So my table looks like this:

```
ID     |     photo      |   ident     | status
------------------------------------------------
80     |    img/photo1  |   ACH3882   |   V
81     |    img/photo2  |   SHD8837   |   V
82     |    img/photo3  |   SFF4837   |   X
83     |    img/photo4  |   DLL3266   |   V
```

Right now, only the `status` columns get colored, but I want the whole row to have color, based on the value in the cell. But I am not sure how to do this.

This is my table, and what I am currently using:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="blueTable" border="2" style= "background-color: #f9f9f9; color: #000000; margin: 0 auto;" >
  <thead style= "background-color: #FFFFFF">
    <tr>
      <th>Photo</th>
      <th>Ident</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
     if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
          $num_rows = 0;
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $num_rows++;
              echo
              "<tr>
              <td>{$row['photo']}</td>
              <td>{$row['ident']}</td>
              <td class='statusclass'>{$row['status']}</td>
              <td><a href='delete.php?id={$row['id']};'>Delete</a></td>
              </tr>";
             
          }
          /*freeresultset*/
          $result->free();
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the script to add color:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".statusclass").each(function(){
      if($(this).text() == "V"){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FFEE58");
      }else if($(this).text() == "X"){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#66BB6A");
      }
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are currently just setting the statusclass class on the status column and not the full row. Have you tried setting class='statusclass' on the tr tag?

Comment: _“Right now, only the status columns get colored”_ - of course, because you only operate on that specific table cell. Go up to the parent element then, and set the color for that instead. (Btw. any specific reason you are doing this in JavaScript - and not in PHP right away?)

Comment: Ah, I see, you got that weird solution from here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63112490/1427878 And you asked there already, about it not coloring the whole row. Please allow people some time to give you _feedback_ in such cases, instead of creating a new question about such a minor detail right away. Plus, it would not go amiss, if you showed a bit of effort here yourself - this site is _not_ a code writing service.

Comment: I would think by simply adding your `statusclass` to the `tr` and having a proper `css` file definition would eliminate the need to JS here.

Comment: @Virre Yes, If I change to this: `"<tr class='statusclass'>` none of the cells gets any color.

Comment: @CBroe Weird solution? How is this a weird solution?

Comment: Because you could set the color right away in PHP here, instead of taking a “javascript detour”.

Comment: _“If I change to this: `<tr class='statusclass'>` none of the cells gets any color.”_ - of course it doesn’t, because there’s _multiple_ parts playing together here. If you change _just_ that, then the JS code will select different elements, the full table row, instead of just a specific cell - and the text of that full row will not equal `V` or `X` any more.

Comment: I am quoting, so that it is clear what I am referring to. Comments in between might be removed later. Not a Miss either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are saying you want the parent element to be colored, so you can use this. Just insert `.parent()` into the lines.

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $(".statusclass").each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == "V"){
          $(this).parent().css("background-color", "#FFEE58");
        }else if($(this).text() == "X"){
          $(this).parent().css("background-color", "#66BB6A");
        }
      })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for actually giving me the solution. Cheers mate!

Comment: Whatever... if you want to clutter your entire site up with needless mounds of javascript for something that is a 100% css-only need... its your bag. Good luck with the project.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I understand your point of view, I myself would have used one class per row, but the perfect setup is not for everyone for various reasons.


For what it's worth @AmenCarb, your PHP code could be 
`<tr class='color-{$row['status']}'>`, 
with CSS-rules `.color-V{ background-color: #FFEE58 } .color-X{ background-color: #66BB6A }`. That should also do the trick

Comment: @jeroenpeters sorry, my comment was more towards the op... as you were only fixing his problem and at the mercy of already bad code he got from his other question ;-)